# AWS Eventbridge to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-event-bridge

I am integrating an AWS partner (Freshservice). I am able to set up an event bus to see the data from the partner, but I need to get the ticket information into S3. I am thinking of using a Glue workflow but I am uncertain if this is the best method. The end result is to have the data available in Quicksight for analytics. Any thoughts on best options?

Answer (score 1):

Solution was not what I thought. I ended up going from Event Bridge -> Kinesis -> S3 -> GLUE -> Athena

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).